# How does implicit/inline/$inject dependency injection work in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm new to AngularJS and I would like to understand more about the dependencies that are being injected by default. While reading through code I've noticed that sometimes dependencies are explicitly declared beforehand, and sometimes they aren't. For example:

```
someModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'someService', function($scope, someService) {
  // ...
}]);
```

Gives the same results as:

```
someModule.controller('MyController', function($scope, someService) {
  // ...
});
```

How does this work? Is Angular assuming that the modules being injected are named the same as the variables in the parameters?

Also, strangely enough, if you do specify the dependencies that are going to be injected, you must specify **all** of them and in the **right order**, otherwise nothing will work. For example, this is broken code:

```
someModule.controller('MyController', ['someService', '$scope', function($scope, someService) {
  // Won't give us any errors, but also won't load the dependencies properly
}]);
```

Can someone clarify to me how is this whole process working? Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, dependency injection in Angular works via the names of the components you (and Angular - for the internal ones) registered.

Below is an example showing how a service is registered and injected into a controller using several different annotations. Please note that dependency injection always works the same in Angular, i.e. it doesn't matter if you are injecting something into a controller, a directive or a service.

```
app.service('myService', function () {
    // registering a component - in this case a service
    // the name is 'myService' and is used to inject this
    // service into other components
});
```

Two use (inject) this component in other components, there are three different annotations I am aware of:

**1. Implicit Annotation**

You can either specify a constructor function which takes as parameters all the dependencies. And yes, the names need to be the same as when these components were registered:

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($http, myService) {
    // ..
});
```

**2. Inline Array Annotation**

Or you can use a notation using an array, where the last parameter is the constructor function with all the injectables (variable names do not matter in this case). The other values in the array need to be strings that match the names of the injectables. Angular can this way detect the order of the injectables and do so appropriately.

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$http', 'myService', function ($h, m) {
    /* Now here you can use all properties of $http by name of $h & myService by m */
    // Example
    $h.x="Putting some value"; // $h will be $http for angular app
}]);
```

**3. $inject Property Annotation**

A third option is to specify the `$inject`-property on the constructor function:

```
function MyController($http, myService) {
    // ..
}
MyController.$inject = ['$http', 'myService'];
app.controller('MyController', MyController);
```

The reason why the last two options are available, at least as far as I know, is due to issues which occured when minifying the JavaScript files which led to the names of the parameters being renamed. Angular then wasn't able to detect what to inject anymore. In the second two cases the injectables are defined as strings, which are not touched during minification.

I would recommend to use version 2 or 3, as version 1 won't work with minification/obfuscation. I prefer version 3 as from my point of view it is the most explicit.

You can find some more detailed information in the internet, e.g. on the [Angular Developer Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

Comment: at "2. Inline Array Annotation": "The other values in the array need to be strings that match the names of the injectables." => I think `$htt` isn't a valid angularjs injectable, maybe @PzYon meant to type `$http` instead?!

Comment: Just wanted to add for those using ng-annotate or ng-annotate-loader: a string literal "ngInject" will do the same thing as option 2 behind the scenes, per this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46556981/1340070

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP was wondering how the inline/implicit DI works under the hood. As in, how does Angular match those up?

Answer (score 2):

Just to provide a different sort of answer, as to the *how* inline/implicit dependencies work in AngularJS. Angular does a `toString` on the provided function and parses the parameter names from the string which is produced. Example:

```
function foo(bar) {}
foo.toString() === "function foo(bar) {}"
```

References:

[source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/auto/injector.js#L78)

[AngularJS Dependency Injection - Demystified](http://anandmanisankar.com/posts/angularjs-dependency-injection-demystified/)