# Undefined object after using Angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

Creaed this service but getting an undefined object error. So the object is null but why, I feel like I'm doing it right.

```
var app = angular.module('rollerApp', []);

app.factory('RollerService', function() {
    var rollers = [
        'roller1',
        'roller2',
        'roller3'
    ];

    return {
        get: function() {
            return rollers;
        },
    };
});

app.controller('Index', ['$scope',function($scope,RollerService) {
    $scope.rollers = RollerService.get;
}]);
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Beginner in overall Javascript so some explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't injected your `RollerService`:

```
app.controller('Index', ['$scope', 'RollerService', function($scope, RollerService) {
  $scope.rollers = RollerService.get;
}]);
```

Angular's dependency injection tries to be smart by analysing the name of your function parameters. However, in order to protect against issues caused by code mangling (which turns parameter names into obscure names like `a`, `b`, etc), you need to explicitly annotate your functions by listing dependencies as strings, before defining the function itself.

Read more:

- [How does implicit dependency injection work in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32753405/how-does-implicit-dependency-injection-work-in-angularjs)
- https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/guide/di

Once you understand how Angular's dependency injection works, you can use a tool like [`ng-annotate`](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) to save you from having to manually set `$inject`.

Comment: I thought I injected it zith the 'RollerService' in the function parameters? Why does it need to be defined twice?

Comment: I think you *can* just use `app.controller('Index', function($scope, RollerService) {...`, but this won't work if you minify your code.

Comment: @Arg0n - that's right, it *will* work when you *minify*, but it *won't* if your minification *mangles* too.

Comment: I see. In either case, you can't MIX defining parameter names and not, choose one and stick to it.