# What does ngInject do in the following piece of code?

Tags: angularjs

AngularJS controller code:

```
function AuthConfig($stateProvider, $httpProvider) {
  'ngInject';

  // Define the routes
  $stateProvider

  .state('app.login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'auth/auth.html',
    title: 'Sign in'
  })

  .state('app.register', {
    url: '/register',
    templateUrl: 'auth/auth.html',
    title: 'Sign up'
  });

};

export default AuthConfig;
```

I am not able to figure out what is the use of ngInject. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`'ngInject';` does nothing by itself, it's just a string literal. A tool called ng-annotate uses it as a flag : if a function starts with `'ngInject';`, it will be processed by ng-annotate.

Basically, ng-annotate will transform

```
angular.module("MyMod").controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $timeout) {
    "ngInject";
    ...
});
```

to

```
angular.module("MyMod").controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", "$timeout", function($scope, $timeout) {
    "ngInject";
    ...
}]);
```

in order to make the code minification-safe.

**If you're not using ng-annotate, you can safely ignore or remove the expression.** Be careful though, you might break the build process of the project if it does use ng-annotate.
For more information about ng-annotate and what it does, see https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think there is a mistake in the second code block - after the transform the `"ngInject"` should not exist anymore, right?

Comment: I have not used ng-annotate in a long time, but according to the examples on the github page, `"ngInject";` stays after the transformation. It would probably be removed during minification though.

Answer (score 3):

Usually ngInject is needed for the application to work when minified once you deploy in production. If you remove it and use optimize version it should fail.

Read more about **[`AngularJs Minification and Annotation`](http://bguiz.github.io/js-standards/angularjs/minification-and-annotation/)**

Comment: Sajeetharan, but I am not able to get why to specifically use ngInject. Exactly what it does?

Comment: @DiscoDancer it preserves integrity of required dependency injections - especially for [strictDi-mode](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.6/docs/error/$injector/strictdi) - throughout your build/minify process. Without this, your declared dependencies may become obfuscated from their declared names and angularjs will not be able to properly inject those required dependencies for your given controller/component/service/etc. It all really depends on your build process and coding style for any given angularjs project.