# Error: "fourSquareService.getVenues is not a function"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-factory

#### AngularJs - how to use factory with form input as part of URL to fetch?

First question here. I am studying angular and was trying to use separated files for my services and also using a user input on a form as part of the request URL. I got it working by injecting $http on my controller and calling the service inside the on click function, but to keep things clean, I really wish to keep services in separed files and call them inside my controller. I've tried to return a one attribute function on my service so I could parse the input (ng-model="cityInput") when calling it. But when I call it on my controller (after adding the service as dependency) it's giving me "fourSquareService.getVenues is not a function" error. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance. **Code below:**

**foursquare service**

```
 // Foursquare API Info
    const clientId = 'PU3IY1PZEOOANTPSHKNMS5HFSMEGEQ1IAVJYGYM4YVZP3NGD';
    const clientSecret = '0V21IXU0EETE3SZJGGCP4T4R13NUTBJ0LMI5WQY45IMDPEKY';
    const url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?near=';
    const imgPrefix = 'https://igx.4sqi.net/img/general/150x200';
    
    // Current day
    function getCurrentDate() {
        let today = new Date();
        let yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        let mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
        let dd = today.getDate();
        if (dd < 10) {
            dd = '0' + dd
        }
        if (mm < 10) {
            mm = '0' + mm
        }
        return yyyy + mm + dd;
    };
    let currentDay = getCurrentDate();
    
    //Foursquare Angular request
    app.factory('fourSquareService', ['$http', function ($http) {
        return {
            getVenues: function(place) {
            const fourSquareURL = `${url}${place}&venuePhotos=1&limit=5&client_id=${clientId}&client_secret=${clientSecret}&v=${currentDay}`;
            return $http.get(fourSquareURL);
        }
    }
    }]);
```

**APIXU service**

```
// APIXU Info
const apiKey = '44972f525fb14478ac0224821182604';
const forecastUrl = 'https://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.json?key=';

//Angular request
app.factory('apixuService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        getForecast: function (place) {
            const apixuURL = `${forecastUrl}${apiKey}&q=${place}&days=4&hour=10`;
            return $http.get(apixuURL);
        },
        getCurrentWeather: function (place) {
            const currentWeatherUrl = `${forecastUrl}${apiKey}&q=${place}`;
            return $http.get(currentWeatherUrl);
        }
    };
}]);
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'apixuService', 'fourSquareService', function ($scope, fourSquareService, apixuService) {
    //Search on Click Function
    $scope.executeSearch = function () {

        //Venues
        fourSquareService.getVenues($scope.cityInput).then(function (response) {
            $scope.fouSquareData = response.data.response
            $scope.destination = $scope.fouSquareData.geocode.displayString;
            $scope.venues = $scope.fouSquareData.groups[0].items.map(spot => spot.venue);
            let photos = [];
            $scope.venues.forEach((venue, index) => venue.photos.groups[0] && venue.url ? photos.push(`<a href="${venue.url}" target="_blank"><img class="venueimg" src="${imgPrefix}${venue.photos.groups[0].items[0].suffix}"/></a>`) : venue.photos.groups[0] ? photos.push(`<img class="venueimg" src="${imgPrefix}${venue.photos.groups[0].items[0].suffix}"/>`) : photos.push('<img class="venueimg" src="./img/320px-No_image_available.png"/>'));
            $scope.photos = photos;
        }, function (error) {
            $scope.showdestination = true;
            $scope.showData = false;
            $scope.destination = 'Place not found, please try again.';
        });

        //Current Weather
        getWeather.getCurrentWeather($scope.cityInput).then(function (response) {
            $scope.currentWeather = response.data.current;
            $scope.place = response.data.location.name;
        });

        //Forecast
        getWeather.getForecast($scope.cityInput).then(function (response) {
            $scope.showdestination = true;
            $scope.showData = true;
            $scope.forecast = response.data.forecast.forecastday;
            const weekDays = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
            $scope.weekDays = [];
            $scope.forecast.forEach(function (day, index) {
                $scope.weekDays[index] = weekDays[(new Date(day.date)).getDay()]
            });
            $scope.weekDays[0] = 'Today';
            $scope.weekDays[1] = 'Tomorrow';
        });

    };

}]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does implicit/inline/$inject dependency injection work in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32753405/how-does-implicit-dependency-injection-work-in-angularjs/32753866#32753866).

Comment: This problem with dependency injection can be avoided by using [implicit annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-annotation). Tools like [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) let you use implicit dependency annotations in your app and automatically add inline array annotations prior to minifying.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mismatch on referencing your dependencies

It should be this

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'apixuService', 'fourSquareService', 
function ($scope, apixuService, fourSquareService) {
        //Search on Click Function
        $scope.executeSearch = function () {

        //Venues
        fourSquareService.getVenues($scope.cityInput).then(function (response) {
            $scope.fouSquareData = response.data.response
            $scope.destination = $scope.fouSquareData.geocode.displayString;
            $scope.venues = $scope.fouSquareData.groups[0].items.map(spot => spot.venue);
            let photos = [];
            $scope.venues.forEach((venue, index) => venue.photos.groups[0] && venue.url ? photos.push(`<a href="${venue.url}" target="_blank"><img class="venueimg" src="${imgPrefix}${venue.photos.groups[0].items[0].suffix}"/></a>`) : venue.photos.groups[0] ? photos.push(`<img class="venueimg" src="${imgPrefix}${venue.photos.groups[0].items[0].suffix}"/>`) : photos.push('<img class="venueimg" src="./img/320px-No_image_available.png"/>'));
            $scope.photos = photos;
        }, function (error) {
            $scope.showdestination = true;
            $scope.showData = false;
            $scope.destination = 'Place not found, please try again.';
        });

        //Current Weather
        apixuService.getCurrentWeather($scope.cityInput).then(function (response) {
            $scope.currentWeather = response.data.current;
            $scope.place = response.data.location.name;
        });

        //Forecast
        apixuService.getForecast($scope.cityInput).then(function (response) {
            $scope.showdestination = true;
            $scope.showData = true;
            $scope.forecast = response.data.forecast.forecastday;
            const weekDays = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
            $scope.weekDays = [];
            $scope.forecast.forEach(function (day, index) {
                $scope.weekDays[index] = weekDays[(new Date(day.date)).getDay()]
            });
            $scope.weekDays[0] = 'Today';
            $scope.weekDays[1] = 'Tomorrow';
        });

    };

}]);
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot to change that before pasting here. Thanks. This controller is based on old names I was using. Anyway its giving me the same error "fourSquareService.getVenues is not a function"

Comment: still your edited post, has a mismatch, did you tried this?

Comment: I got kinda lost in my editions and now it is working after I changed the order inside the function parameters to match the same order on the service dependecies. Is this order important? Didn't know that

Comment: Yes, it is important.

Comment: Didn't know that till now. Thank you very much =)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the order of the parameters inside the controller function to match the same order of the depedencies and it worked! Didn't know the order was important.

**working controller:**

```
 app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'fourSquareService', 'apixuService', 
function ($scope, fourSquareService, apixuService) {
        //Search on Click Function
        $scope.executeSearch = function () {

            //Venues
            fourSquareService.getVenues($scope.cityInput).then(function (response) {
                $scope.fouSquareData = response.data.response
                $scope.destination = $scope.fouSquareData.geocode.displayString;
                $scope.venues = $scope.fouSquareData.groups[0].items.map(spot => spot.venue);
                let photos = [];
                $scope.venues.forEach((venue, index) => venue.photos.groups[0] && venue.url ? photos.push(`<a href="${venue.url}" target="_blank"><img class="venueimg" src="${imgPrefix}${venue.photos.groups[0].items[0].suffix}"/></a>`) : venue.photos.groups[0] ? photos.push(`<img class="venueimg" src="${imgPrefix}${venue.photos.groups[0].items[0].suffix}"/>`) : photos.push('<img class="venueimg" src="./img/320px-No_image_available.png"/>'));
                $scope.photos = photos;
            }, function (error) {
                $scope.showdestination = true;
                $scope.showData = false;
                $scope.destination = 'Place not found, please try again.';
            });

            //Current Weather
            apixuService.getCurrentWeather($scope.cityInput).then(function (response) {
                $scope.currentWeather = response.data.current;
                $scope.place = response.data.location.name;
            });

            //Forecast
            apixuService.getForecast($scope.cityInput).then(function (response) {
                $scope.showdestination = true;
                $scope.showData = true;
                $scope.forecast = response.data.forecast.forecastday;
                const weekDays = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
                $scope.weekDays = [];
                $scope.forecast.forEach(function (day, index) {
                    $scope.weekDays[index] = weekDays[(new Date(day.date)).getDay()]
                });
                $scope.weekDays[0] = 'Today';
                $scope.weekDays[1] = 'Tomorrow';
            });

        };

    }]);
```

Comment: This problem with dependency injection can be avoided by using [implicit annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-annotation). Tools like [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) let you use implicit dependency annotations in your app and automatically add inline array annotations prior to minifying.